# Running my Backbone Render function on a selected route?

Tags: php, backbone.js

I have a PHP Slim and Backbone.JS setup and all my code is now working without any problems.

The only issue I have is that the code I have is minified into one file with Grunt.JS and is loaded at the bottom of each page.

So my Backbone render call is fired on all my pages within my site and not just the path I want it to run on.

I have now tried to use Backbones Router to fire the render on the path I want it to run on, I did not think this would work and it did not as I am using PHP slim as the routing agent and of course Backbone needs a  `/#/`  route path.

Now when I had this Backbone route set up I did try to get PHP Slim to redirect the  `/#/`  route to the clean PHP Slim route path. PHP Slim did not like this at all, when I use the following code,

```
$app->get('/#/MYPATHHERE', function () use ($app) {

   $app->redirect('/REALLPATHTOGOTO');

});
```

it gave me a PHP Slim error, it looks like PHP Slim does not like the  `/#/`  route.

So what is the best method for doing this?

I am thinking that I could just call the render function within the PHP page that I am getting PHP Slim to render on my selected route? or is there a better method for doing this?

Thanks

Glenn.

Answer (score 1):

Ok got this to work with Backbone, did some more research and enabling pushState to true on the Backbone.history.start then it works without the need for the hash routing.